# Is it possible to create a CRM workflow that updates "Modified By" field?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow

I want to create a CRM workflow that updates the "Modified By" field based on a text field called "Prepared By".  "Prepared By" contains a user's full name.  Is this possible?

When I try to add an "Update Record" step in my workflow, it doesn't seem to let me update the "Modified By" field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map a lookup field using a text field value in UI Workflow. I would recommend you to go for code solution. ie. plugin or custom workflow activity - where we can use C# SDK to update the value.

You can do a `RetrieveMultiple` or below LINQ example for finding the `SystemUser` record using the text value from the `Prepared By` attribute & set the `ModifiedBy` field `EntityReference`. This can be done in either pre or post operation.

```
Entity _user = context.CreateQuery("systemuser").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname").Equals(fullname)).FirstOrDefault();

if (_user != null)
{
    _target["modifiedby"] = _user.ToEntityReference();
}

//assign new target to plugin executioncontext
pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] = _target;
```

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/08/26/change-createdby-modifiedby-field-at-runtime-in-dynamics-crm-plugin)

Comment: I am fairly new to coding and working with Custom Workflow Activities.  Am I able to just create a Visual C# class, copy the code in the reference, and import the solution to CRM?  I tried to do that but received quite a few errors.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimG create a separate question & share the code where you are facing issues.. but close this question if my answer helped you